# Closure (the good way book)

Tags: javascript, closures

I am going over the 4th chapter of this book and have run into a problem on the code below. This code goes right over my head and I cant seem to figure out why the (i) is there. He explains in the book but its just not that great of an explanation.

```
  //Make a function that assigns event handler functions to an array of nodes the right way
  //When you click on a node, an alert box will display the ordinal of the node.

    var add_the_handlers = function(nodes){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1){
            nodes[i].onclick = function(i){
                return function (e){
                    alert(i);
                };
            }(i); // <-------------this i  right here.
        }
    };
```

Comment: could you be more specific? what is unclear to you here?

Comment: You're confused about `i`? `i` is used to keep track of the index when iterating over the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: ok i should of been more clear. Edited.

Comment: @Ian well there are **two** variables called "i" in the code above; that's the non-obvious part.

Comment: @Pointy Great point, I didn't think of that confusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting `(someValue)` after a function expression will immediately call that function.

```
foo = function (i){ ... }(i);
```

will give you the same result as:

```
bar = function (i){ ... };
foo = bar(i);
```

By having a locally scoped variable `i` inside that function (defined via `function (i)`), the value is captured (closed over) and won't change when the other `i` (the one in scope outside the function) changes (which it will every time you go around the loop).

I'd generally use a different name for the variable inside the closure. Duplicate variable names can be confusing.

```
nodes[i].onclick = function(closed_over_i){
    return function (e){
        alert(closed_over_i);
    };
}(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `(i)` calls the first anonymous function immediately, meaning that `nodes[i].onclick` gets the second anonymous function.

There are actually two `i`s there which may be confusing the issue a bit - there is one in the scope of the `add_the_handlers` function, and another in the `onclick` function.

I'll rewrite it and number the lines to help explain:

```
1.  var add_the_handlers = function (nodes) {
2.      var i;
3.      for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1){
4.          nodes[i].onclick = function (j) {
5.              return function (e) {
6.                  alert(j);
7.              };
8.          }(i);
9.      }
10. };
```

This is functionally identical to your original code; because they're different scopes, your version can have the same variable name without them interfering with each other; it's just a new variable `i` which is only available within that function. I've changed it to `j` just to make it clearer where the two scopes are.

On line 4 you define an anonymous function which takes a single argument `j`, and then call it immediately on line 8 with the current value of `i`. You do this to create a new scope, copying the **current** value of `i` into it. The value of `j` is no longer linked to the `i` being incremented by the loop.

This means that you can now define the second anonymous function on line 5 (the closure) in that new scope, so `j` will always refer to the variable in that scope. You then return that function and assign it to `nodes[i].onclick`, so when it is called it will always alert the value of `i` that it was when it was defined, even thought it is now called in a different scope.

Without the function call on line 8, the `i` on line 6 of your example would be in the scope of the outer function starting at line 1; because that value is changed in the loop on line 3 for each item in the array, all `onclick` functions would alert the final value of `i`, `nodes.length`.

The example code is just a more compact and confusing way of writing:

```
var create_closure = function (val) {
    // This val is in a separate scope to the i
    return function (e) {
        // This is the closure; it references a variable in the parent scope
        alert(val);
    };
};

var add_the_handlers = function (nodes){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i += 1) {
        nodes[i].onclick = create_closure(i);
    }
};
```

Although the example is making a point, in general this will be a better way to write the solution - less nesting and a named function makes it clearer to anyone coming along afterwards, and less likely you'll make a mistake with it later. At the very least use a different variable name in your closure.